# If $f(\theta) = sin(\theta) = 0.1$, then find $f(\theta +\pi) = sin(\theta + \pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I know the answer is $- 0.1$, but I'm not sure how to show my work analytically. My reasoning is that a $\pi$ shift changes the $0.1$ into a negative number, just like in the unit circle. How do you analytically find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using the summation formula for sines

$$\sin (x + y) = \sin (x)\cos (y) + \sin (y)\cos (x)$$

just set $y = \pi $ and you get

$$\eqalign{
  & \sin (x + \pi ) = \sin (x)\cos (\pi ) + \sin (\pi )\cos (x)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \sin (x)\left( { - 1} \right) + 0\cos (x) =  - \sin (x) \cr} $$

Answer (score 2):

Simply you may use the formula: $$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+ \cos(a)\sin(b) $$